# Intersect two lists with different types

Tags: java, sql

I have two lists: `List<Employee>` and `List<Vacancy>`
Employee has id, firstname, lastname and List
Vacancy has id, name, and Employee field.

In database Vacancy table has employee_id

I fetch data from mysql db and map it to pojo (Employee or Vacancy).
As output I have `List<Employee>` and `List<Vacancy>`. 
How can I get employee by vacancy name or get vacancy by employee name? Maybe I need smth like a intersection of two lists.

Comment: Use a join query and make a `Map<Employee, List<Vacancy>>`  or Map<Vacancy, Employee>??

Comment: Maybe you need a Base-Class like Object to concat the two lists?

Comment: Not sure to understand, you have a name and want to find which Employee / Vacancy corresponds to it ? (Maybe if you provide an example it will be easier to understand)